# Any way to execute sequential queries in one Mongo round trip?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a DB that holds updates with their commit timestamps.  I want to find the difference between the most recent update and the update from 12 hours ago.  The timestamps aren't exactly 12 hours apart, so we need to get the max timestamp that's at least 12 hours old.

This query is pretty complicated to write as a single Mongo command.  But it is easy to write as a sequence of commands:

- x = getMaxTimestamp
- y = getMaxTimestamp where timestamp < (x - 12
  hours)
- Get (val, timestamp) where timestamp = x or y

and find the differences on the client.

Doing these as three round-trip queries, though, is obviously sub-optimal.  It would be better if I could just tell Mongo to run them sequentially and pass the values in.  Something like the WITH statement in SQL.  Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/boosting-javascript-from-mongo-shell-to-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with aggregation:

- [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html#sort-aggregation) by timestamp, descending.  An index on the timestamp field would greatly improve performance of this sort
- [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html#limit-aggregation) stage to return the first document
- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-aggregation) in the same collection, using the [pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#uncorrelated-subquery) form, [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#subtract-aggregation) 12 hours worth of milliseconds from the timestamp, `$match` documents with older timestamps, and `$limit` to pick the first
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#project-aggregation) to `$subtract` the timestamps and select other fields to return.

Comment: Actually `y` depends on `x`, so you can't use `$facet` here